# How to load TreeView data only once in a _Layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

Our users asked to have the Kendo Tree show up in the MVC web app in a panel on the left hand side of the page. They want that left hand panel to be present on every screen.

Currently I have a section of my _Layout.cshtml page that renders the Kendo Tree:

```
<div>
  @{Html.RenderAction("GetTree", "Tree");}
</div>
```

Inside that Action I make a database call to get the contents of the tree and bind the model to the view as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>
```

But obviously with this pattern every page I go to the _Layout gets called and the tree data is fetched from the database again. This is not very efficient.

What is a better way so that I only make a single database call?

Comment: Is the content of the tree the same for every page and every user?

Comment: put a if(TreeViewItemModel == null)  somewhere  , where ever it is that it is loaded , incorporate some type of cacheing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the content of the tree is the same for every page and every user.

In that case, you can cache the retrieved database data so that you don't have to retrieve it on every page render.  There are lots of ways to cache it:  the simplest is probably to use ASP.NET's own caching, which is described in detail (with walkthroughs) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx).

You probably will still have to render it on every page (unless you want to get into partial page caching, and I'm not sure how that works in MVC) but you definitely can avoid the repeated database hit.

ETA:  You can create a wrapper or helper class that retrieves the necessary tree data by company.  The relevant method would look a bit like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> GetCachedTreeDataByCompany(int companyId)
{
    var data = Cache["TreeData"] as IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>;
    if(data == null)
    {
        data = GetTreeData();  // whatever you need to do to get the data
        Cache.Insert("TreeData", data);
    }
    return data.Where(tvim => tvim.CompanyId == companyId).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The content is different based on which Company the user belongs to, but I am storing the CompanyId in the Session and using that to make the database call to get the Tree data.

Comment: I understand a cache is an option, was also looking to see if people had other ideas or patterns that might be more appropriate for this scenario, like possibly not using the _Layout at all for this part of the design

Comment: So cache may be an option but it would have to be separated per Company

Comment: @cktech  I have added to my answer to show how you could cache the entire collection of TreeViewModelItems but pull only the records for the relevant company.  You could also have separate caches by company ID, by using a calculated key for each cached collection that incorporated the company id.  There are many other possible ways to set it up.

Comment: I have not implemented the cache solution yet but this answer sounds reasonable and does stop multiple db hits. thank you Ann.